# LET with LOOP construct in Common Lisp

Tags: loops, common-lisp, let

I have the following code:

```
(let (liste (loop for item from 1 to 20 collect item))
  (format t "~{~a~}~" liste))
```

However `portacle` complains: `The variable FOR is unbound.` Why?

Comment: The error is caused, because you try to initialize the variable (!) LOOP to the value of FOR (because, as Will Ness says, the syntax for LET would require a list of variable descriptions. Generally you might complain to the maintainers of the Lisp implementation for a better error report, since the thing is violating the LET syntax , which should be mentioned as an error - particularly if you use a compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your code, CLISP complains:

```
*** - LET: illegal variable specification
       (LOOP FOR ITEM FROM 1 TO 20 COLLECT ITEM)
```

So the problem is with `LET`, not with `LOOP`.

You are missing an additional pair of parentheses:

```
;;;    v                                               v
(let ( (liste (loop for item from 1 to 20 collect item)) )
  (format t "~{~a~}~" liste))
```

This will give you a different error message, concerning the format directive.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, the parentheses... And with the directive, you were absolutely right: `(format t "~{~a~}" liste)`